# Minimax selection- what if there is two possibilities?

Tags: algorithm

So I was reading about minimax trees and I implemented an algorithm for minimax.  However, I have a question.

Let's first assume that we have the following TWO tree branches separated by AND (note, not logical AND, I am just separating the two branches):

```
-1, 1 AND 0, 1

where -1 = loss, 0 = tie, 1 = win
```

According to the minimax algorithm- if we select MAX on these branches then the MAX will be one.  Our recursive function will return 1 for BOTH of these branches.

However, it is clear that one branch (0, 1) is better than (-1, 1).  But our algorithm could select EITHER ONE of these branches.

Is this a well known problem with the minimax algorithm- or am I thinking about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking about it the wrong way.

The 'MAX' algorithm is looking for the best result from the tree.  In this case, either branch has a best result of a win and hence from the 'MAX' point of view they're equal as either one can lead to a win.